# Install Redmine + Mercuria , push, abort: authorization failed

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, installation, redmine

I try to follow this manual. 
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowToInstallRedmineOnUbuntuServer

I have, Desktop Ubuntu 11.04 on VMware

By manual I have done the following:

- Pre-install
- Redmine Installation
- Apache Integration
- Mercurial Integration

Everything seems to works and looks fine.(web interface ok, clone test repo ok)

But when I:

```
hg push
pushing to http://192.168.1.10/hg/test
searching for changes
http authorization required
realm: Redmine Mercurial Repository
user: i try, root, linux user, mysql, redmine user
password:....
abort: authorization failed
```

I do not know what username and password he wants. In var/hg/hgweb.config

```
[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
```

In Apache config file

```
<Location /hg  >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine Mercurial Repository" 
    Require valid-user
```

Comment: For your info, [BitNami](http://bitnami.org) proposes lots of pre-installed vm. One of them includes redmine: http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a word on this website about running htaccess, which is going to create user/password to log in with.  That is required for your AuthType Basic to work.   Also, you don't want to use AuthType Basics, you really want to use at least the Digest type (it uses a decent hash).

Comment: I try: sudo htpasswd -c /var/hg/.htpasswd dev; and add to /etc/apache2/conf.d/hg.config AuthUserFile /var/hg/.htpasswd, restart apache -> login with user "dev" and pass -> same error (abort: authorization failed)